# Nested object in Elasticsearch Using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have created a nested object in our index mapping as shown:

```
.Nested<Bedroom>(n=>n.Name(c=>c.Beds).IncludeInParent(true).Properties(pp=>pp
.Number(d => d.Name(c => c.BedId).Type(NumberType.Long))
.Number(d => d.Name(c => c.PropertyId).Type(NumberType.Long))
.Number(d => d.Name(c => c.SingleDoubleShared).Type(NumberType.Integer))
.Number(d => d.Name(c => c.Price).Type(NumberType.Integer))
.Number(d => d.Name(c => c.RentFrequency).Type(NumberType.Integer))
.Date(d => d.Name(c => c.AvailableFrom))
.Boolean(d => d.Name(c => c.Ensuite))
```

However we are experiencing 2 problems.

1- The AvailableFrom field does not get included in the index mapping (the following show the missing field from Kibana index pattern page)

```
beds.bedId
beds.ensuite
beds.price
beds.propertyId
beds.rentFrequency
beds.singleDoubleShared
```

Thanks JFM for a constructive comment. This is that part of the mapping in Elastic

```
    "beds" : {
      "type" : "nested",
      "include_in_parent" : true,
      "properties" : {
        "availableFrom" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "bedId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "ensuite" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "price" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "propertyId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "rentFrequency" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "singleDoubleShared" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
      }
```

I can see the availablfrom here but not in the index pattern?
Why

2- When we try to index a document with a nested object, the whole Application (MVC Core 3) crashes.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: what version of NEST are you using? What version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? Can you show a complete but succinct reproducible example?

Comment: Would be nice to have a look at the actual mapping as well, Run GET my_index in Kibana and take a look at the actual mapping. If no mapping for AvailableFrom has been provided and no AvialableFrom provided there might not be a mapping set for it (yet). Hence the index pattern not knowing about the non-existent field

Comment: @JFM Thanks for you constructive comment. I have amended the question. The index shows it but the index pattern does not, even though it shows all the others. Any idea how (these days) a library like NEST can blow up a whole application that is hosting it? Surely at worst case it should throw exceptions unless it was written by a dog with very bad hangover! This library is just a disaster.

Comment: @user2981411 did you fixed this problem? How you solved the issue? Thank you for sharing